# captureVisibleTab text rendering is blurry

Tags: google-chrome-extension, retina-display

I seem to get noticeably lower quality text rendering from captureVisibleTab than I see on screen. From what I've read, captureVisibleTab just grabs its image from memory (see Chromium issue 44758), so I'm not quite sure why this would be. I've got a retina MacBook but the images are noticeably worse on a regular screen too. I'm writing an extension for a web typography tool that depends specifically on text rendering so any workaround or alternative approach would be much appreciated.

Here's a screenshot of the BBC home page as I see it:

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s1/sh/e49a2865-cac5-4f57-b9fe-0703d5676ca2/ebb6455a83a15d70ea99f0c153001947/deep/0/Screen%20Shot%202013-03-20%20at%2023.31.23.jpg

And the dataURI loaded with the following code:

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {format: "png"}, function(dataURI) {
    console.log(dataURI);
});
```

Looks like this:

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s1/sh/295c8694-5f34-4b37-a754-b396644b0b82/55e1466a939d0f8e5677b25a93c5bc2b/deep/0/Screen%20Shot%202013-03-20%20at%2023.33.59.jpg

(Open those two screenshots in tabs and flick back and forth between them to see what I mean.)

Answer (score 1):

try changing the format to a jpeg and making the quality higher

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed this answer. I did try jpeg on the highest quality too - no difference, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a known issue in Chromium - [code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=415297](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=415297)